# Make cells have the same size between seaborn heatmaps

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am making two `seaborn` heatmaps, which I am putting into two `matplotlib` subplots, like so:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True, figsize=(5,10))


data = [
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
]
sns.heatmap(
        data, 
        ax=axes[0],
        linewidths=0.2,
        cbar=False)


data = [
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
]
sns.heatmap(
        data, 
        ax=axes[1],
        linewidths=0.2,
        cbar=False)

axes[0].set_title("A")
axes[1].set_title('B')
```

[image]

As you can see, this results in subplot A and B. The individual cells within subplot A are all the same size. The cells within subplot B are also all the same size. However, the cells between A and B are different sizes. How can I make sure that the size of cells between the subplots are the same?

I understand that means that plot A would overall be larger then plot B, which is not an issue.

Comment: The answer to [Seaborn correlation heatmap with equal cell size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64173951/seaborn-correlation-heatmap-with-equal-cell-size) resizes the axes to make the cells of equal size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to change the size ratio of the two subplots.

If the size ratio between plot A and B is set to be the same as the ratio between the number of rows for plot A and B, the size should be (more or less) the same.

```
data_a = [
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
]
data_b = [
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, 
        sharex=True, 
        figsize=(5,10), 
        gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [len(data_a), len(data_b)]})


sns.heatmap(
        data_a, 
        ax=axes[0],
        linewidths=0.2,
        cbar=False)

sns.heatmap(
        data_b, 
        ax=axes[1],
        linewidths=0.2,
        cbar=False)

axes[0].set_title("A")
axes[1].set_title('B')
```

[image]

I am wondering if there is also a seaborn option that can be toggled to get this behavior?

Comment: You could use `axes[0].set_aspect(0.5)` and `axes[1].set_aspect(0.5)` (or some similar number) to really force the cells to be equally sized.  The grid_spec will still be needed to get the approximate sizes (the grid reserves space for titles and labels).